# warning: implicit declaration of function 'fsync' is invalid in C99

Tags: c, macos, compilation, posix, clang

For some reason when I compile my code the compiler does not find the prototypes for fsync and truncate. I get this:

```
cc -c -Wall -Wno-overflow  -pedantic -std=c99 -I/Users/matt/Programming/BitEagle_Projects/cbitcoin/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/opt/local/include -O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -D_POSIX_SOURCE -fPIC dependencies/storage/CBBlockChainStorage.c -o build/CBBlockChainStorage.o
dependencies/storage/CBBlockChainStorage.c:154:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fsync'
      is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                if(fsync(indexAppend)){
                   ^
dependencies/storage/CBBlockChainStorage.c:649:6: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'truncate' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        if (truncate(filename, CBArrayToInt32(data, 0))) {
            ^
```

What do I have to do to remove these warnings? I am including unistd.h. This is on OSX using clang:

```
$ cc --version
Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

Thank you.

Comment: What header files have you included?

Comment: Did you include the corresponding header file in your code? There is an `fsync` prototype in `unistd.h` in Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `-std=c99`, the system headers will attempt to provide a declaration/macro namespace compatible with the C standard, which does not include any of the additional functions from POSIX or other standard or nonstandard extensions. You need to define the appropriate *feature test macros* to get them. For example, put `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` on the command line or define it in your source files.

Comment: If you are using POSIX extensions you should use `-std=gnu99`

Comment: @benjarobin Unless you don't want to enable the gnu extensions. Using additional functions is a different thing.

Comment: Actually not. `-std=gnu99` makes a lot of changes at the compiler level that cause it to be non-conforming to C99 -- things like turning on math "optimizations" that give wrong results. My view is that you should always use `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` and the appropriate feature test macros for the library features you want, e.g. `-D_GNU_SOURCE` if you want all GNU library extensions.

Comment: _POSIX_SOURCE is deprecated and only able to request the original 1990s-era version of POSIX, which probably lacked fsync.